# Why this integral give the $F$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am studying about hydraulic jump in trapezoidal channel:
[image]

In the picture where I draw braces I want to find the force to the small triangle. I know the force is product of pressure and Area ($F=PA$) here pressure to the triangle is $P=\rho gy$ and in the picture we can see it says $\delta F=\rho gy. x(Y-y) \delta y$
And then integrated it.
I don't understand why the area of triangle  calculated like that. And why the integral with bounds $y=0$ to $Y$ give us the $F$.
I really try to understand the formula instead of memorizing it. So I appriciate any help

EDIT: I just relized $y$ is the deapth of flow.

Comment: The height of the trapezoid is $Y$, so the bounds of the integral from $0$ to $Y$ should make sense. Perform the integration of $\delta  F$ from 0 to $Y$ to see why $F$ is equal to what it is.

Comment: @tangentboundle Oh I got it. But I don't understand why $\delta F=\rho g y.x(Y-y)\delta y$

Comment: And why we have $x(Y-y)$ as the base of triangle?

Comment: I think the formula obtained by using horizontal Riemann integral sums!